# Calling SOAP UI mock service with WCF: "The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'."

Tags: wcf, http, https

A colleague of mine gave me a copy of a mock service project for SOAP UI. I can open and run this mock service fine on my machine. 
It is running at address: http://localhost:8088/mockShipmentInformationService

The WSDL is provided on address: http://localhost:8088/mockShipmentInformationService_SOAPBinding?WSDL

Using the WSDL provided, I added a Service Reference to the application project. In order to test the methods calling the service, I also added the service reference to the Unit testing project.

For both projects, the following is added to the app.config:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ShipmentInformationService_SOAPBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:8088/mockShipmentInformationService_SOAPBinding"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ShipmentInformationService_SOAPBinding"
        contract="ShipmentInformationService.ShipmentInformationService"
        name="ShipmentInformationServicePort" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

As you can see, the URL is using the normal http protocol, not https. Also, my security mode is set to "none". Yet, I keep on getting the following error message, when attempting to call the service method:

```
 The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'.
 Parameter name: via
```

What gives? Might there be some URLs defined somewhere that are wreaking havoc? Where should I look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just discovered that it was all in the app.config files. The application project had a wrong URL in the applicationSettings section and the URL wasn't present there for the unit testing project. I can now at least call the service, although I am having some other issues now.